# awk extended pattern matching (embedding pattern matching in actions for already matched strings)

Tags: regex, awk, pattern-matching, gawk

I want handle strings of the form:

```
PREFIX_TYPE_N,DATA
```

So, does the *awk (gawk, mawk, nawk) support including pattern matching in the action for already matched string? Something like this (of course, doesn't work for me):

```
*awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
     /PREFIX/ {
                /TYPE_1/  {printf "[TYPE1] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- included pattern 
                /TYPE_2/  {printf "[TYPE2] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- another included pattern
                ...                                        // <-- some more included patterns
              }' "filename"
```

Or do I still need if/else or switch/case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite in that way, but pretty close, as there is a regular expression match operator (~):

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
/PREFIX/ {
            if ($1 ~ "TYPE_1") {printf "[TYPE1] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- included pattern 
            if ($1 ~ "TYPE_2") {printf "[TYPE2] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- another included pattern
            ...                                        // <-- some more included patterns
          }
```

Note that because the first pattern match will already enter its block with only one row processed, it's fine to have only ifs in the block.

If you really want the legibility of patterns, you could do this:

```
BEGIN { FS="," }
/PREFIX/ { //stuff to do for all prefixes, before specific handling
          data = $2 }
/PREFIX_TYPE_1/ { type = "TYPE_1"; }
/PREFIX_TYPE_2/ { type = "TYPE_2"; }
/PREFIX/ { //stuff to do for all prefixes, after specific handling 
          printf("[%s] [DATA: $2]", type, data)
          }
```

Comment: this works well and fast, even with if-s. the second case helped me too, but for another problem. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way in gawk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="," }
     /PREFIX/ {
                if (/TYPE_1/)  {printf "[TYPE1] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- included pattern 
                if (/TYPE_2/)  {printf "[TYPE2] [DATA: $2]"}    // <-- another included pattern
                ...                                        // <-- some more included patterns
              }' "filename"
```

Here `/TYPE_1/` is equivalent of `$0 ~ /TYPE_1/`. Look for details in [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Expressions) (part 6.1.2).

Comment: thank you for a new coding trick ;) this works the same speed as with $2! I thought it should be a little bit slower (because of pattern matching for the bigger string: $1 << whole string)